# Validation error language in asp.NET dynamic data WEB-site

Tags: asp.net, validation, .net-4.0, dynamic-data

I need to change language of validation error to another language. Validation logic must not be changed.

I just want to translate **The field f5080eb8_0a83_4b89_b339_233528441711 must be a valid integer.** into another language. For example from English into Italian.

I search in Visual Studio(Entire Solution) for this texts

1. must be a valid integer
2. The field

result=0. So, what is the best way to translate validation error text into another language?

Some ideas, 
         thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this problem for ASP.net Dynamic Data localization?  I'm stuck, I've translated all the other texts into French, but I can't find this one.  The message is inside the RequiredFieldValidator control, but surely it should detect the current user's language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically do all translation activities in .NET with the Resources system: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I am familiar with this technology. But the question about asp.Net Dynamic Data Site, it is not clear where stored these strings.

Comment: @loviji: Read the article. It shows you were to store the strings. I don't know what you mean by "Dynamic Data". Is that some sort of product? Nevertheless, the same rules apply. Anywhere you set a string manually, you can use a local/global resource string instead.